# Error when building on server: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID

Tags: c#, tfs, visual-studio-2013

I'm using Visual Studio 2013. In my program I create an Excel document. It works fine, but when I try build this solution on build server , the server throws this exception:

```
Result:System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Retrieving the COM class   factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
at AutomatedTest.AutoStatistic.AutoConvert(String pathOld, String pathNew, String pathLog, String pathToDocuments) in...
```

On this line:

```
 Application xlApp = new Application();
```

I don't want to install Visual Studio on my build server. What do I need to install on the build server, so that the build will compile properly?

P.S. My program build on platform x86.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Excel that is missing from the build server, not Visual Studio.

BUT running Office from a Windows service like TFS Build is completely unsupported (see [KB 257757](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)).